# Grails Gorm DDL fails in Postgres 9 when lazy loading enum type

Tags: grails, enums, grails-orm, postgresql-9.1

Consider the following domain classes in Grails:

```
enum MyEnum { One, Two, Three }

class MyClass {
    Collection mys = []
    static hasMany = [
        mys: MyEnum
    ]
    static mapping = {
        mys lazy: true
    }
}
```

When running the app with 'create-drop' on a Postgres 9.1 database I get the following error:

```
Unsuccessful: create table myclass_mys (myclass_id int8, myenum varchar(-1))
ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
```

The error disappears if I remove the lazy mapping. However, the lazy is necessary for other reasons. My current workaround is to create the database without the lazy mapping and change domain classes afterwards which is very annoying in a development context.

Any ideas about how to fix the gorm mapping so that varchar(-1) will be varchar(255) as usual?

Comment: do you use a specific dialect in DataSources.groovy?

Comment: I tried both org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect and net.sf.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect with same result.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use a enum in a domain class but don't specify a mapping for the enum, your table is created normally. Although, if you mention your enum property in the mapping block, you'll have problems. There is a workaround adding a mapping like this to your property:

```
sqlType: "varchar(20)"
```

So you could try but I don't know if this works in a joinTable though. Take a look at this jira issue for more info: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8444